# How to format JSON data to objective-c variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

In my iOS app, I'm fetching some notification data. This data is formatted like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "to": "1",
        "from": "0",
        "text": "Person X liked photo Y.",
        "read": "1",
        "date": "1 month ago"
    },
    {
        "to": "1",
        "from": "0",
        "text": "Person X liked status Y.",
        "read": "1",
        "date": "1 month ago"
    },
    {
        "to": "1",
        "from": "0",
        "text": "Person X wants to be your friend.",
        "read": "1",
        "date": "1 month ago"
    },
    {
        "to": "1",
        "from": "0",
        "text": "Person X is a bit of a stalker.",
        "read": "1",
        "date": "1 month ago"
    },
]
}
```

I know how to format JSON data with only one variable in the `data` element, but this one has got an array with content. What do I need to change in the code below?

```
NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.notificationData length]);

// convert to JSON
NSError *notificationError = nil;
NSDictionary *notificationRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.notificationData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

NSLog(@"%@", notificationRes);

// extract specific value...
NSDictionary *notificationSwitchValues = [notificationRes objectForKey:@"data"];

NSLog(@"%@", notificationSwitchValues);

NSString *text = [notificationSwitchValues objectForKey:@"text"];

NSLog(@"%@", text);
```

Comment: Your code is broken as it assumes all the values in the dictionary are strings.  However, as you say yourself the `data` value is an array so that code would not work even if there is only one element in the array.  Then later it assumes that `data` is a dictionary.  What's going on?

Comment: This is the code I normally use to parse JSON to usable data. But, yes, normally it fetches strings. So how could I change the code above to read all the `text` variables?

Comment: So the question is how to iterate an `NSArray`.  Search for "objective-c fast enumeration".

Comment: you can directly convert you 'NSArray' or dictionary into object model  by using https://github.com/jigneshagola/JSJSONParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[notificationRes objectForKey:@"data"]` is array so it need to be

```
NSArray *notificationSwitchValues = notificationRes[@"data"];
NSLog(@"%@", notificationSwitchValues);
for (NSDictionary *notificationSwitchValue in notificationSwitchValues) {
    NSString *text = notificationSwitchValue[@"text"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *notificationSwitchValues = [notificationRes objectForKey:@"data"];
```

The above code should be replaced to

```
 NSArray *notificationSwitchValues = [notificationRes objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Then access element from array and it will be again a dictionary.Then access elements from last dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *entitys = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in notificationRes) {
    StrangeJSONData *strangeJSONData = [StrangeJSONData strangeJSONDataFromDictionary:dictionary];
    [entitys addObject:strangeJSONData];
}

@interface StrangeJSONData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *to;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *from;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *read;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
+ (instancetype)strangeJSONDataFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end

@implementation StrangeJSONData

+ (instancetype)strangeJSONDataFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    StrangeJSONData *strangeJSONData = [[StrangeJSONData alloc] init];
    strangeJSONData.to = dictionary[@"to"];
    strangeJSONData.from = dictionary[@"from"];
    strangeJSONData.read = dictionary[@"read"];
    strangeJSONData.date = dictionary[@"date"];
    strangeJSONData.date = dictionary[@"text"];
    return strangeJSONData;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you some of the 3rd party open-source libraries that can do it for you and offer many other features.

**Try one of these:**

- Mantle: https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle
- JSONModel: http://www.jsonmodel.com